# Unity console not showing Debug upon pressing play

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, debugging, console.log

I am creating a small login page example and upon pressing play I am not getting any of the Debug messages I am expected if the email/password/confirm password is not according to the conditions set.

Here is the whole code:

Packages

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Class definition

```
public class Register : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject username;
    public GameObject email;
    public GameObject password;
    public GameObject confPassword;

    private string Username;
    private string Email;
    private string Password;
    private string ConfPassword;

    private string form;
    private bool EmailValid = false;
    private string[] Characters =  {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z",
                                    "A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","O","N","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z",
                                    "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","_","-" };
```

Initiation and setting conditions for username, email, password and confirm password.

```
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    public void RegisterButton()
    {
        print("Registration Successful");

        bool UN = false;
        bool EM = false;
        bool PW = false;
        bool CPW = false;

        if (Username != "")
        {
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(@"E:/UnityTestFolder/" + Username + ".txt"))
            {
                UN = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Username Taken");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Username field empty");
        }

        if (Email != "")
        {
            EmailValidation();
            if (EmailValid)
            {
                if (Email.Contains("@"))
                {
                    if (Email.Contains("."))
                    {
                        EM = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Debug.LogWarning("Email is incorrect");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.LogWarning("Email is incorrect");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Email is incorrect");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Email field empty ");
        }

        if (Password != "")
        {
            if (Password.Length > 5)
            {
                PW = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Pass must be at least 6 characters long!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Password field empty");
        }

        if (ConfPassword != "")
        {
            if (ConfPassword == Password)
            {
                CPW = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogWarning("Passwords do not match!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Confirm password field empty");
        }

        if (UN == true &&EM == true &&PW == true &&CPW == true)
        {
            bool Clear = true;
            int i = 1;
            foreach (char c in Password)
            {
                if (Clear)
                {
                    Password = "";
                    Clear = false;
                }
                i++;
                char Encrypted = (char)(c * i);
                Password += Encrypted.ToString();
            }
            form = (Username + "\n" + Email + "\n" + Password);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"E:/ UnityTestFolder / " + Username + ".txt", form);
            username.GetComponent<InputField>().text = "";
            email.GetComponent<InputField>().text = "";
            password.GetComponent<InputField>().text = "";
            confPassword.GetComponent<InputField>().text = "";

            print("Registration complete");
        }


    }
```

Calling update - pressing tab button to navigate between the various placeholders.

```
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab))
        {
            if (username.GetComponent<InputField>().isFocused)
            {
                email.GetComponent<InputField>().Select();
            }
            if (email.GetComponent<InputField>().isFocused)
            {
                password.GetComponent<InputField>().Select();
            }
            if (password.GetComponent<InputField>().isFocused)
            {
                confPassword.GetComponent<InputField>().Select();
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return))
        {
            if (Password != ""&&Email != ""&&Password != ""&&ConfPassword != "")
                {
                RegisterButton();
                }
        }

        Username = username.GetComponent<InputField>().text;
        Email = email.GetComponent<InputField>().text;
        Password = password.GetComponent<InputField>().text;
        ConfPassword = confPassword.GetComponent<InputField>().text;

    }

    void EmailValidation()
    {
        bool SW = false;
        bool EW = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < Characters.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Email.StartsWith(Characters[i]))
            {
                SW = true;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < Characters.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Email.EndsWith(Characters[i]))
            {
                EW = true;
            }
        }
        if (SW = true &&EW == true)
        {
            EmailValid = true;
        }
        else
        {
            EmailValid = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Add [ExecuteInEditMode] attribute here:

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class Register : MonoBehaviour
```

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ExecuteInEditMode.html - check this page. You have some limitation when executing scripts in Edit Mode.

Comment: Thanks, I tried various option but nothing. When I introduced various errors of various types in my script it does pick it up but the ones I conditioned to appear does not appear in console when I click ```Register``` on Unity.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it, it was a stupid mistake, I just had the wrong `GameObject` in the "On Click" component.

Thanks for all help again.